# PostgreSQL как правильно распарсить массив строк JSON без кавычек?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть упрощённый код:

```
SELECT value::VARCHAR(100) FROM jsonb_array_elements('["1", 1, 2, 3, 4, "4"]')
```

Мягко скажем, поведение данного кода огорчает.
Есть способ нормально запарсить подобный массив без костылей?
См. скрин, зачем-то в выводе для строк парсер json оставляет двойные кавычки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нахрапом в гугле е нашёл

Comment: Чего нашёл-то? Если ответ, то поделись

Comment: не нашёл)) "н" не пропечаталась) А ответ внизу помог

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо вам нужно это:

```
select value::varchar(100) from jsonb_array_elements_text('["1", 1, 2, 3, 4, "4"]');
```

Вяло искали, в документации это следующая строка таблицы после `jsonb_array_elements`: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/15/functions-json#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE

Comment: Дело было вечером, устал уже) Ну пусть будет)) спасибо!